# WOS2 Sending File by SFTP with Guaranteed Delivery

Tags: ftp, wso2, esb, vfs, transport

I have a question regarding the following scenario: I want to pick up a file from an SFTP server using the WSO2 VFS transport. This file should then be passed on to a target system using e.g. SOAP. One requirement I have is that the file mustn't get lost in case the WSO2 goes down. I know about the Enterprise Integration Pattern "Guaranteed Delivery" and how it is implemented with WSO2 (https://docs.wso2.com/display/IntegrationPat-terns/Guaranteed+Delivery).

Is there a gap between picking up the file from the SFTP server and writing it to the message store that could lead to a complete loss of the read file in case the WSO2 server goes down? Is a special configuration of the VSF transport (https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB470/VFS+Transport) recommended?

I would really appreciate if you might share any experiences or recommendations related to these questions.

Kind regards,

Heiko

Answer (score 0):

If any error happens while reading file form SFTP location, you can set an error location parameter to move that file to that particular location. Later you can process the files from the error location.

Comment: Hello Rahtha, thank's for your reply. What will happen if the incoming file was read from the source directroy but not yet written to the error location directory. Can I be sure that, when e.g. the WSO2 process gets killed, the read file is not lost? Cheers, Heiko